# Is there a way to hide the mat-radio-button in Angular and make the image inside it clickable instead?

Tags: html, angular, sass, material-table

[This is how it looks till now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21qE5.png) Im trying to hide the radio button and use an image for male and female instead. This is the html code for the mat-radio-group:

```
   <mat-radio-group formControlName="gender">
            <mat-label>
              <mat-radio-button class="female-radio" value="M"></mat-radio-button>
              <img width="100" src={{imageTwo}}>
              </mat-label>
              <mat-label>
                <mat-radio-button class="female-radio" value="F"></mat-radio-button>
                <img width="100" src={{imageOne}}>
              </mat-label>
          </mat-radio-group>
```

And in my scss component I did:

```
.female-radio + img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mat-radio-checked + img {
  outline: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

What do I do to show only the images in order to select the gender?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please make below changes in your component html

```html
<mat-radio-group formControlName="gender">
  <mat-label>
    <mat-radio-button class="female-radio" value="M">
      <img width="100" src={{imageTwo}}>
    </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-label>
    <mat-label>
      <mat-radio-button class="female-radio" value="F">
        <img width="100" src={{imageOne}}>
      </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-label>
</mat-radio-group>
```

and add below css to the css/scss file

```css
:host ::ng-deep .mat-radio-container {
  display: none;
}
```

This will display just the images and the functionality will remain as is. The value of the selected item can still be accessible in the formControlName `gender`.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. This did the job. But now the outline i did for the image in css wont show? I only saw that your way worked after I checked if the data were saved to db. Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: remove + from css

Answer (score 0):

**If there have much more radio buttons then you can hide them by class name**

[image]

```
<mat-radio-group class="only-image" [(ngModel)]="gender" >
  <mat-label>
    <mat-radio-button class="female-radio" value="M"></mat-radio-button>
    <img (click)="genderChange('M')"
      width="100"
      src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/male-sign-flat-illustration-vector-600w-1483957736.jpg"
    />
  </mat-label>
  <mat-label>
    <mat-radio-button class="female-radio" value="F"></mat-radio-button>
    <img
    (click)="genderChange('F')"
      width="100"
      src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-illustration/male-icon-clipping-path-600w-135680966.jpg"
    />
  </mat-label>
</mat-radio-group>
```

// css

```
.female-radio {
   display: none;
 }
```